# are all values put into a variable treated as strings?

Tags: string, variables, python-3.x, int

In python, if I assign a 1 to x (x = 1), is that 1 regarded as a string every time?

I don't get why numbers aren't treated as numbers and have to be converted into
recognized integers for math operations. It seems like a hassle to keep having to change
variable values back and forth.

thank you

Part 2:
Some code for area of circle program:

```
def chooseDim ( ):
    **choice = input ('Do you need to find radius or area? ')
    if choice == 'A' or 'a':
        area = 0                [This part of the prog is the culprit, specifically the
        area = int(area)         "choice" variable prior to the If conditional. The If 
        areaSol ( )**           keeps reading the condition as True no matter what value
                                "choice" is. It has to do w/the "or" condition. When I let
                                "choice" be one value, it's fine, but if I code
                                "if choice = 'A' or 'a'"  the prog evals the If as True                  
                                every time. Am I not coding the "or" statement right?]

    elif choice == 'R' or 'r':

        radSol ( )

    else:
        print ('Please enter either A/a or R/r.')
        chooseDim ( )
```

Answer (score 0):

No. All values are not converted into strings. Python, while being "dynamically typed" in the sense that a variable may contain different types of values over its lifetime, is generally pretty strict about operations (you can't just concatenate a number onto a string, for instance). If you assign a number into a variable, the value will be a number.

If you have a problem with a specific piece of code, how about posting it?

Answer (score 0):

No what you say is not correct. Python is dynamically typed that means that while variables do *not* have types, its values do have types. You can easily check that by using the `type` function to get a value’s type:

```py
>>> x = 1
>>> type(x)
<class 'int'>
>>> x = '1' # storing a different value in x
>>> type(x)
<class 'str'>
>>> type(1) # type() works on the value, so this works too
<class 'int'>
>>> type('1')
<class 'str'>
```

Python is however also strongly typed, that means that no dynamic type conversions are made. This is the reason that you have to convert string explicitely to numbers when performing arithmetic operations:

```py
>>> 1 + '1' # int does not allow addition of a string
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    1 + '1'
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

>>> '1' + 1 # on the other hand, int cannot be converted to str implicitely
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    '1' + 1
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

#### edit

To respond to the code you posted, your if is like this:

```py
if choice == 'A' or 'a':
```

This checks, if `choice == 'A'` (if `choice` equals to `'A'`), **or** if `'a'` evaluates to `True`. As `'a'` is a non-empty string it will always evaluate to true, so the condition is always true. What you want to write is this:

```py
if choice == 'A' or choice == 'a':
```

Comment: very helpful; i started w/python only last week after a long hiatus from programming (COBOL, JCL); the "type" command will be most useful

Comment: def chooseDim ( ):     #to find area/radius of circle
    choice = input ('Do you need to find radius or area?')
    if choice == 'A' or 'a':
        area = 0
        area = int(area)
        areaSol ( )

    elif choice == 'R' or 'r':
        radius = 0
        radius = int(radius)
        radSol ( )

    else:
        print ('Please enter either A/a or R/r.')
        chooseDim ( )

Comment: @Fluxcapacitor Can you add that code into the question? It’s not readable in the comments (especially as Python requires whitespace).

Comment: pardon the mess; i'm having trouble w/this editor; i type the stuff out nice and neat and it gets crunched; i will rework it

Comment: I will submit this question as a new post. Look for it.